# connect to mssql on linux via odbc

Tags: c++, sql-server, odbc

I connected MSSQL (on windows) via odbc on linux redhat 64bit.
Below is odbc and freetds configuration files.

`freetds.conf`:

```
[FreeTDS]  
host=172.21.32.20  
port=1433  
tds version=7.2  
client charset = GB2312
```

`odbcinst.ini`:

```
[TDS]  
Description = TDS  
Driver = /usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so  
Trace = Yes  
TraceFile=/tmp/odbcinst.log  
UsageCount = 1
```

`odbc.ini`:

```
[SQLSERVER]  
Driver = TDS  
Description = sql server dsn  
Trace = NO  
Server = 172.21.32.20  
Database = Live  
Port = 1433  
TDS_Version = 7.2  
TraceFile=/tmp/sqlserver.log
```

Snippets:

```
QString f3ErpDsn = QString::fromLocal8Bit("Driver={SQLSERVER};server=172.21.32.20;database=Live;uid=inp;pwd=inp;");
QSqlDatabase f3ErpDb= QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
f3ErpDb.setDatabaseName(f3ErpDsn);
// f3ErpDb.setDatabaseName("SQLSERVER");
f3ErpDb.setUserName("inp");
f3ErpDb.setPassword("inp");
QString sqlCmdStr = "select * from dbo.Table_Drilling_Data01 where status=1";
if ( ! f3ErpDb.open() )
{
        qDebug() << f3ErpDb.lastError().text();
        return 1;
}
QSqlTableModel model;
model.setTable("dbo.Table_Drilling_Data01");
model.setFilter("status=3");
model.select();
qDebug() << model.lastError().text();
```

Error messages:

1. `f3ErpDb.setDatabaseName(f3ErpDsn);`
   If `setDatabaseName` is `f3ErpDsn` error message is:

   > "QODBC3: Unable to connect", "[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified")

   I had defined SQLSERVER in odbc.ini. Why it can not find it?
2. But if I changed `f3ErpDb.setDatabaseName("SQLSERVER");`, error message is:

   > "[FreeTDS][SQL Server]The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 1 (""): Data type 0x00 is unknown. QODBC3: Unable to execute statement"

It makes me confounded, could anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what QSqlDatabase is. But it seems that you have improper SQL connection string.

Try something like this:

```
UID=inp;PWD=inp;DSN=SQLSERVER;database=Live;SERVER=AMIN\SQLEXPRESS;charset=UTF-8
```

`DSN=SQLSERVER` because `SQLSERVER` is the only DSN which defined in your `odbc.ini`

`SERVER=AMIN\SQLEXPRESS` - try Windows name of SQL Server, not host's IP address (I'm not sure that IP is not allowed here, but Windows name is 100% working)

Comment: but this code runs successful on windows.   and i connected database via freetds perfectly.

Comment: hmm, could you provide your windows ODBC settings? You see, when you write "Driver={SQLSERVER};server=172.21.32.20;database=Live;uid=inp;pwd=inp;", you don't provide DSN at all, so you don't use odbc.ini settings. On the other hand, you didn't specify driver named SQLSERVER in odbcinst.ini, so your connection string will not work. Specify DSN=SQLSERVER or Driver={TDS} in connection string

Comment: ------------- ODBCINST.ini -------------                               [SQL Server (32 λ)] \n                             
Driver=C:\WINDOWS\system32\sqlsrv32.dll  
Setup=C:\WINDOWS\system32\sqlsrv32.dll  
32Bit=1  there is not any setting about sqlserver in ODBC.INI file.

Comment: by the way, do you know how to create new line in comment? when i press "Enter" key, it saves the comment.

Comment: anybody know? my odbc driver problem

Comment: i connected it perfectly via isql or tsql(unixODBC). so i think maybe problem is DSN,

Comment: Ken, did you try my advise? In the very beginning you didn't specify DSN in connection string at all. It was a problem (at least)

Comment: i am wrong. if i changed QString f3ErpDsn = QString::fromLocal8Bit("Driver=TDS;server=172.21.32.20;database=Live;uid=inp;pwd‌​=inp;"); it said "[unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source QODBC3: Unable to connect" . but it didn't say why.

Comment: if i changed QString f3ErpDsn = QString::fromLocal8Bit("DSN=SQLSERVER"); it said [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified")

Comment: anybody know? it confuse me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solve it when I changed TDS protocol to 8.0, it was at 7.0 before. I've used freetds, unixodbc, via Qt to connect to MSSQL database.